# Content Security Policy blocking 'eval' in Laravel project on live server - Page content not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, content-security-policy

Description:
I am currently facing an issue with my Laravel project when deployed to a live server. It seems that the Content Security Policy (CSP) is blocking the use of 'eval' in JavaScript, and as a result, my content is not displaying as expected.

Problem:

1. The content displays correctly in a local environment but encounters issues on the live server.
2. After investigating, it appears that the CSP is blocking the 'eval' function in JavaScript, which is used in my project.

I am seeking guidance on how to address this issue. Thanks!

$response->header('Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only', "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css https://cdn.bootstrap.com;; report-uri /csp-report-endpoint");

Tried changing my CSP to Report-Only, it ignore the security issue but not the 'eval' error. and the content still not displayed on the live server

Comment: is there any way at all you can stop using `eval`?

Comment: i've check my js, there no such function as eval were being use

Comment: `the 'eval' error` ... what error? or by "eval error" do you mean some CSP message? I mean, you say there is "an error" ... exactly what error are you seeing?

Comment: was the `build` successful? Are you using outdated Plugins or libraries? Try auditing your NPM packages if you are using vuejs